# ffmpeg -to with -ss before input file

Tags: ffmpeg

Using ffmpeg in the order `ffmpeg -ss 00:04:21 -i "filename.mp4" -to 00:04:47 -c copy "output.mp4"` is far faster than switching the order of the -ss and -i flags but `-ss` causes the timestamps to be incorrect for the `-to` flag, making them not match and the `-to` not correspond to the correct time in the source file. Adding `-copyts` fixes this issue and trims it to the correct the time, but causes the timestamps to show the original's in the output file, i.e. the time in the output file starts at 4:47 on any viewer despite the video only being 26 seconds long.

Using the order `ffmpeg -i "filename.mp4" -ss 00:04:21 -to 00:04:47 -c copy "output.mp4"` fixes the issue at the cost of a much longer execution time.

Is there any way to get the best of both such that it seeks to the correct time before opening the file while still being fast?

Comment: Place -ss/-to both before input.

Comment: -to is an output modifier so cannot be placed before the input unfortunately.

Comment: Your ffmpeg is too old. `-to` is available as input option since 4.0

Comment: So it is, wasn't flagged by my package manager because whole distro was out of date. Thank you for the help. Would you like to post a solution so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FFmpeg, by default, normalizes input timestamps to start from 0. So, the `-to` as an output option effectively becomes a duration limiter. `-copyts` avoids that by not resetting the timestamps. However, some players may not gracefully handle non-zero start times.

Using `-to` as input option (available since v4.0) achieves your goal.